# ¿Cómo llenar select con ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, array

Muestro un pedazo del HTML y Javascript, la parte del del HTML igual tengo un input donde almaceno un id y el nombre del grupo, entonces la respuesta del ajax del javascript si me trae los datos y si lleno esos input, pero no logro llenar el select con los elementos que me trae

**HTML**

```
<select class="duallistbox" multiple="multiple" id="editarPermisos" name="editarPermisos[]">
        <?php
             $permisos = ControladorOtros::ctrMostrarPermisos();
             foreach ($permisos as $key => $value) {
                     echo '<option value="'.$value["nombre_permiso"].'">'.$value["nombre_permiso"].'</option>';
             }

        ?>
</select>
```

**JS grupos.js**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditarGrupo", function(){

var id_grupo = $(this).attr("id_grupo");

var datos = new FormData();
datos.append("id_grupo", id_grupo);

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/grupos.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(respuesta){

        $("#editarNombreGrupo").val(respuesta["nombre_grupo"]);
        $("#id_grupo").val(respuesta["id_grupo"]);

        var values = respuesta["permisos"].toString();
        values = values.split(",");
        $.each(values, function(i,e){
            $("#editarPermisos option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
        })

    }

})
})
```

Ahora el siguiente código:

```
var values = ["Crear usuarios","Editar usuarios","Eliminar usuarios"].toString();
    values = values.split(",");
        $.each(values, function(i,e){
            $("#editarPermisos option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
        })
```

Si lo pongo fuera de todo el ajax osea a raíz de grupos.js si funciona y hace lo que quiero que hiciera pero con array que traigo de la base de datos, ya que si se fijan en este pedacito he puesto un array manualmente, pero yo el mio el que quiero dentro de la respuesta ajax la traigo desde la base de datos

Anexo una imagen del resultado que me deberia de dar con la respuesta ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me haya dado a entender y espero me puedan ayudar

La siguiente imagen es lo que me sale en consola después de hacer el split

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `console.log(values);` puesto **después** de hacer el `split`. Sin ver lo que hay en las variables no podemos adivinar el problema. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta con lo que has encontrando depurando el código.

Comment: Listo he puesto lo que me sale por consola

Comment: Se agradece que en vez de una imagen pongas el texto en sí mismo. De todos modos, eso no parece un JSON válido, ese **montón de comillas simples por todos lados** sobran. ¿Podrías mostrar cómo manejas la petición y la respuesta en `grupos.ajax.php`?

Comment: O quizá eso lo está provocando el `.toString()`, prueba a crear `values` de este modo, sin más: `var values = respuesta["permisos"];` o múestranos un `console.log(respuesta);` directamente. Me parece que estás mareando demasiado los datos.

Comment: Sigue mostrando lo mismo y es que sabes qué, el código que si me muestra lo que debe si lo pongo igual dentro de la respuesta ajax tampoco funciona, entonces antes de dar solución a el porque me muestra asi los datos, seria bueno primero dar solución a el porqué no funciona ese código que si sirve fuera

Comment: En Ajax el código funcionará dependiendo de lo que haya en `respuesta` y de qué estructura tenga, por eso te pedí que mostrarás el `console.log(respuesta);` **dentro de Ajax** para ver qué es lo que hay ahí. No es lo mismo que algo que escribes a mano, porque Ajax depende del servidor, de errores, de que estés mandando las cosas ordenadas de otro modo, etc.

Comment: No veo que hayas puesto el código de **ajax/grupos.ajax.php** y seria interesante ver como montas esa salida, pues es la que recibes después en el ajax y según dices ya parece que venga mal por esas dichosas comillas

Comment: Miren, si pongo el código que si sirve dentro de la respuesta ajax deja de funcionar, cosa que @A.Cedano dice que no debería de pasar, entonces no sé cuál sea el problema

y miren si pongo el código dentro de la respuesta ajax, me muestra esto por consola:

(3) ['Crear usuarios', 'Editar usuarios', 'Eliminar usuarios']
0:  "Crear usuarios"
1:  "Editar usuarios"
2:  "Eliminar usuarios"



y esa misma respuesta me aparece si lo pongo fuera de la respuesta ajax, que es donde si sirve

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu último comentario. A ver: cuando haces una petición Ajax es para solicitar algo en el servidor, ese algo estará en `respuesta` que es el parámetro que tienes en `success` y el uso que hagas de eso dependerá de la estructura de lo que hayas mandado desde el servidor. No tiene sentido que pongas algo a mano, imaginando que viene así desde el servidor, puede que no venga así (como lo pones tú a mano), porque pudo haber un error en el servidor, o porque no estás estructurando los datos así en el servidor. No sé por qué te empeñas entonces en tu ejemplo hecho a mano.

Comment: Bueno creo que detecte el problema, estoy usando AdminLTE y use un select de los que hay ahí, el cual es el que me esta causando el problema, aunque la verdad esta raro, porque bueno use un select multiple normal y a mi respuesta le puse un JSON.parse y en ese select si me muestra el resultado, pero por alguna razón el selec que quiero usar el cual es el de una de mis imagenes no funciona al momento de pasarle esos valores, pero si le paso el array fuera de la respuesta si sirve, es algo muy raro, entonces yo creo que tendré que buscar otras opciones

aun asi gracias por su tiempo :D

Answer (score 0):

Solo te faltaría agregar el `refresh` del `duallist` así:

```
$("#editarPermisos").bootstrapDualListbox('refresh');
```